# Is there a genus-one curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with no points over any solvable extension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, elliptic-curves

Is there a (non-singular) genus-one curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that is known to have no points over any solvable extension?

Comment: If $E$ is defined by $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, then extension containing solution $\alpha$ of $1=x^3+ax+b$ is solvable, and then $(\alpha,1)$ is a point on $E$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I meant genus-one curve, not elliptic curve. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and depending on who you talk to, it is expected that no such curves exist.

The [Çiperiani-Wiles theorem](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/mirela/solvable.pdf) says that every genus one curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with semistable Jacobian and local points everywhere must have a point over some solvable extension. As far as I know, both conditions are expected to be able to be removed, so that every genus one curve has a solvable point.

In fact, Mazur has [speculated](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/plclarkarxiv8v2.pdf) [Remark 4.6] that every genus one curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ should have a point over a metabelian extension.